# How to bypass a screen using navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am coming from android.
In android ,if i want to bypass an activity i will call intent method in onCreate something like this.

```
onCreate(){
    if(condition satisfied){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
   }
}
```

But i cant understand how to write this code in flutter and navigate another screen .
And I also don't know that this code will write in `initState()` or `build()`.
note: In this case in If condition, I used `StreamBuilder`,

I need in following steps,
At screen start

1. Blank screen
2. if Condition will be true than return Container();
3. else leave this Screen(Activity) go to another screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

`return isSomethingtrue ? HomeScreen()  : OtherScreen(),`

Then - In your HomeScreen() Build a Container()

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: in build or initState();

Comment: build is return Widget , so how to saw Navigator as wiidget

Comment: How to show Homescreen or otherscreen as widget

Comment: Like this (see answer)